# Does React create a deep or shallow copy of prevState internally?

Tags: reactjs, state, immutability, setstate

I'm just starting with programming and have recently written my first app in React, and while it does work, I'm not sure if I'm handling my internal state correctly. My question is whether the setState method creates an immutable deep copy of the "prevState" or not necessarily? To show an example:

```
 menuAddRecHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedState = {...prevState};
      const dayInd = updatedState.menu.recipes.findIndex(item => item.dayNum === updatedState.menuInternal.currentDay);
      updatedState.menu.recipes[dayInd].recList.push({
        name: prevState.menuInternal.menuRecSelect,
        portions: prevState.menuInternal.menuNumPortInput
      });
      return updatedState;
    })
  }
```

In my handler I am pushing an object to a nested array of the updatedState object which was copied over from prevState by the spread operator. Now I know that the spread operator makes only a shallow copy, but is the prevState supplied internally by the setState method also shallow, and does that mean that I am actually mutating my state directly by invoking this handler? If so, how do I fix this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> The first argument is an updater function with the signature:
>
> `(state, props) => stateChange`
>
> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props.

How can you achieve the same result without mutating?

```
menuAddRecHandler = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      menu: {
        ...prevState.menu,
        recipes: prevState.menu.recipes.map((item) => {
          if(item.dayNum === prevState.menuInternal.currentDay) {
            return {
              ...item,
              recList: [
                ...item.recList,
                {
                  name: prevState.menuInternal.menuRecSelect,
                  portions: prevState.menuInternal.menuNumPortInput
                }
              ]
            }
          }
          return item;
        })
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This is obviously very error prone, the idea is to have less deeper states. The docs for Redux [offer some tips for normalizing state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).

You can also look at immutable state libraries like [ImmutableJS](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) or [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer)

Comment: Much better answer.

Comment: Very nice answer, the links will certainly be useful for the author to make more maintainable state.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will now focus on learning Redux to clean up the mess I've made.

Comment: @Glogov No, you don't have to learn Redux, the link is only for normalizing state, it can be applied to local state as well. There is a [page in redux docs](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#should-you-use-redux) that help you evaluate if you need redux

Comment: @Agney I'll look into it, right now I'm reading about the Immer library that you mentioned. It seems like a nice, not to complicated way to solve my problem with this particular app. Thank you for bringing it up.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) its's not a copy at all

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated.

Making a deep copy is usually bad for performance, but if you have to do it, you can do something like this:

```
const updatedState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState));
```

Comment: I see. Your method should do the trick, since it is a relatively small application. But, I understand that I should not have been creating such a nested internal state in the first place?

Comment: Yes, having a very deep state makes it quite hard to work with and expensive to modify (you would need to at least recreate every object that is a parent of the value you are modifying)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of "noise" in your example so I'll keep it simple:

```
state = {  name: `Dennis`, age: 89 }

this.setState((prevState) => {
  return { age: prevState.age + 1 }; 
}); // { name: `Dennis`, age: 90 }

this.setState({ name: `John` }); // { name: `John`, age: 89 }
```

In class component, [`this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) **merges shallowly** with the previous state, and the `prevState` is the actual state reference i.e: `{  name: "Dennis", age: 89 }`.

> Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with state.

Note that it is not [the case with functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) (a common mistake).

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects.